# How to create a user that doesn't show up on the login screen?

Tags: login, login-manager

I need to run the web browser with another user but I don't want the user to be shown at the login screen. How can I create a user that will not be listed on the login screen? GNOME/Scientific Linux 6.3.

Comment: Read about gdm setup. Or simply uninstall gdm and use xdm.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/77617/87552

Comment: @Eddy_Em it's probably the worst solution - unistalling anything.

Comment: On Fedora 20 with Gnome 3 for me greeter solution didn't work.
What worked is giving `UID` lower than `50` to the needed users. I actually tried `UID` *23* and *24*.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/545764/17060

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit [`/etc/gdm/custom.conf`](http://projects.gnome.org/gdm/docs/2.14/configuration.html) and add or change the `Exclude` directive in the `[greeter]` section:

```
[greeter]
Exclude=nobody,alice,bob
```

Users `alice` and `bob` won't be shown on the list at the login screen but can still log in by typing their name and password (if they have a password).

See more details in [How to hide users from the GDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2471/how-to-hide-users-from-the-gdm-login-screen)
(it's mostly distribution-independent — some details might change, for example files may located in different places, and the threshold for system users is 500 on most Red Hat derivatives but 1000 on most Debian derivatives).

Comment: For some configurations, the file to edit is /etc/mdm/mdm.conf.

Comment: For future reference, making `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` a link makes it hard to select to copy (at least in my Firefox).

Comment: I've a question, why would someone want to hide their account?

Answer (score 5):

Create *system* user account - with UID less than 1000. Accounts with UID less than 1000 are hidden in gdm and probably others display managers.

You can create *system* account by running `useradd` with `-r` flag.

Comment: -r -> Create a system account with a UID less than 500 and without a home directory.

Comment: I need to run the webbrowser with another user but I don't want the user to be shown at the login screen.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

https://askbot.fedoraproject.org/en/question/43367/how-to-hide-certain-users-from-gdm-logon-list/

In the directory /var/lib/AccountsService/users edit the file for the username to be excluded (copy another one if it does not exist), and set `SystemAccount=true`. Restart the gdm3 service (as root) with

```
# systemctl restart gdm3.service
```

If you are in a gdm session you will be logged out, and the excluded user will not show on the login screen.

Comment: I confirm that this does work. I had the opposite issue, my user got hidden after upgrading to Fedora 31. And there was a file with my user name inside `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/` after editing it (I had to delete the line `SystemAccount=true` as changing it to false wasn't enough) and restarting the GDM service, I could see again my user. I hope this additional info can help someone else.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/a/545764/17060

Answer (score 0):

```
 gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list 1
```

maybe this will be the solution, but I need to test it. Thanks!