# Show one user on login screen

Tags: linux, gnome, alma-linux

I've manage to hide all user from showing up on the login screen on AlmaLinux 8 by doing the follow:

Create the gdm keyfile /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-login-screen and added the following line:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
# Do not show the user list
disable-user-list=true
```

Is there a way to set it so it only display on user?

Comment: related: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64584/332764](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64584/332764)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script to remove the user from the login list. You'll need to login and then logout again for that changes to take effect.

```
#!/bin/bash
userlist=( slee schhean nagios dorder1 dorder2 dorder3 )

for user in "${userlist[@]}"
do
    cat <<-'EOF' > /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$user
    [User]
    Language=
    XSession=gnome
    SystemAccount=true
    EOF
done
```